# Laptop screen starts blinking when on cooling pad

Tags: laptop, display

I have Asus Vivobook Pro N580VD, I have the latest drivers installed, when I check the graphic cards from device manager it says they work properly, I made stress test to the CPU and GPU etc. etc. - all fine! Maybe this would be an useful information for you: The speakers (which have magnets) are on the bottom. Also it has all the 4 rubbers on the bottom.

- About a month ago I bought a cooling pad which you can see it [here](http://www.deepcool.com/product/nbcooler/upto156/2014-02/28_799.shtml). It
  clearly has metal base. Everything worked like charm for two weeks.
  Then, my laptop started to blink (entire screen black for half a second then back to normal, pause for 5-10 seconds then was blinking again) and continued even when I was putting the 
  cooling pad away. It wouldn't stop until I turn the laptop off, wait for a minute and
  turn it on again (tried with the laptop plugged in and out - the result was the
  same). I suspected on short circuit caused by smashed cable (which was a 
  little bit - I am not sure of it) so I cut off that part of the cable, put it 
  back together, tried it with smartphone charger and it was okay.
- Tried to work with the cooling pad again so it started blinking again. I started experimenting this time:
      **1)** Used extension cord - I used smartphone charger to power the cooling pad. Didn't help. 
      **2)** Turned off the computer, waited a little. Turned it on. Everything was fine until.. this time I unplugged the laptop from the charger and I left the cooling pad on the extension cord. Blinked again. I started suspecting it was induction causing the problem.
     **3)** **Unplugged the cooling pad**. This time I just let the computer work laying over the unplugged/turned off cooling pad. For my surprise it started blinking again.

  - Finally borrowed cooling pad from my colleague. I let the computer work over it for an hour or two. Everything was fine until it started blinking again.
    **4)** Lastly I suspected on the angle the laptop was. I let it work on 20 degree angle (as the coolers were) - it doesn't blink.
  - What do I do wrong? How do I cool my laptop down? When it's not over a cooling pad there is no problem at all!

Comment: It sounds like a loose connection inside the device. Warm temperatures make metal expand, cool temperatures make it contract. It sounds like there is a very loose contact, but just loose enough to cause this behavior. It would require you to open the laptop up, and find the ribbon cable and reseat it.

Comment: but if so, when I turn the laptop on it is very cool. It doesn't blink. Now I have a cooling fan pointed at it plus it lays over match cases. It is pretty cool.

Comment: Warm and cool make the ribbon cable move ever so slightly. But its only a theory, though it is one that perfectly explains what is happening.